# How to handle custom files runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have made an application that decrypts a custom file to `XML` file. Then reads that `XML` and save the configuration to some properties and encrypt the file. All I do these things line-by-line.

Now suppose that I encrypted the file, and when I am reading the data from `XML` or do any other thing before `Encrypt` the file again, error occurs, the `XML` file remains at the destination folder. Now this `XML` or `Custom File` must not be read by user. But in this case, both the files exists at the destination folder, which should not happen.

I delete the `XML` file after encrypting it.

Below is code snippet

```
//// Below is the class that Decrypts the file.
DcrFl.DecryptFile(Application.StartUpPath + @"\CustomFile.custom", 
    Application.StartUpPath + @"\CustomFile" + ".xml");

DataSet dsXMlFile = new DataSet();
dsXMlFile.ReadXml(Application.StartUpPath + @"\CustomFile.xml");

PropertyOne = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableOne"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
PropertyTwo = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableOne"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
PropertyThree = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableOne"].Rows[0][3].ToString();

PropertyTemp = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableTwo"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
PropertyTemp2 = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableTwo"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
PropertyTemp3 = dsXMlFile.Tables["TableTwo"].Rows[0][3].ToString();

//// Do other things...

FormDemo formDemo = new FormDemo();
formDemo.Show();
```

Now in `FormDemo` `form`, I `encrypt` the `XML` file to `.custom`.
What is the query with this is, if at `//// Do other things...` an error is occurring, application shuts down and both the files `XML` and `.custom` are present in `Application.StartUpPath`.

One more thing, if the user is able to force close the application, or open `Applicaiton.StartUpPath` the files are accessible. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: If you don't want to save your file on disk why are you saving it to disk, especially to such not-normally-writable location as application folder?

Comment: Like @Alexei says, decrypt to memory, not disk. Also, I hope you didn't write your own encryption algorithm..

Comment: @Blorgbeard:- I don't know how to write a file to memory. Do I have to make `Memory Mapped File`?

Comment: I don't know how your `DecryptFile` method works currently, but you could make it output to a `MemoryStream` and then pass that to `ReadXml` instead of a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider trying this:

1. [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [Simple implementation of 3DES String Encryption/Decryption](http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/basic-encryptiondecryption-c/)